# What is meant by 'resolved', speaking of variables in a JavaScript function's scope?

Tags: javascript, scope

I've come across many versions of this statement recently:

> Each function object has its own set of variables, which are *resolved*
>   in each function’s scope.

I understand scope, but I'm having trouble finding (via Googling) much out about what the word 'resolve' means in this context.

Comment: I think it means finding out what they are. If you use `var x` anywhere, then you have a local `x` regardless of any other `x` in outer functions, or a global `x`. If you say `y = 10`, then the function will try to set a local `y` to `10` if it exists; if it doesn't, it will set the `y` of the closest outer function; if even that cannot be found, you've just created a global `y` with a value of `10`.

Comment: dystroy's answer is correct, and I just wanted to mention that the term "resolution" is basically informal banter that refers to what is formally called *binding* in things like second-order predicate logic and lambda calculus. so your confusion is understandable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolution here is the process by which the variable is found when you have its name.

In the words of the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3.1) :

> Identifier resolution is the process of determining the binding of an
>   Identifier using the LexicalEnvironment of the running execution
>   context

In the case of nested scopes, you start with the most inner scope and you go outside until you find a variable with the name you have.

Here's a very basic example :

```
var a = 1;
function fun(){
  var a = 2;
     console.log(a); 
}
fun(); // logs 2
```

Here's a not trivial example introducing the closure :

```
var a = 1;
function make_fun(a){
  return function(){
     console.log(a); 
  }
}
var fun = make_fun(2);
fun(); // logs 2
```

When `f` is created, it takes the variables of the outer scope (the call of `make_fun` which builds a closure), among them you have `a`.

It's important to remember that scopes in JavaScript (well, before ES6) are

- the global scope
- function calls

Blocks don't create scopes.

Comment: I'm just waiting for you to elaborate to give you the +1.

Comment: could you include a basic example?

Comment: So, when it 'takes' A, you would say that A has been resolved?

Comment: @dystroy got it. It all makes sense now. Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 2):

Variable names are "searched" inside the scope which really is the "this" object or the global object.

The search "resolves" a name like "myproperty" into a reference to the object or value.

So resolving means translating a name representation in your code into a reference inside the JS engine, which is done at runtime.

Some engines (like Google's V8) use dynamic programming to speed up resolution on subsequent passes.

Example:

```
var o = { hello : { my : { obj : "ciao" } } };

alert(o.hello.my.obj); // will display "ciao"
```

Those are three object literals nested inside each other. Each "link" in the chain will require the engine to search for that name inside the object:

```
hello inside o
my inside o.hello
obj inside o.hello.my
```